# get optarg with getopt

Tags: c, getopt

I have the following code:

```
char opt;
int bla1,bla2,bla3;
char *myarg = NULL;
while((opt = getopt(argc,argv,"a:b:cd")) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
        case 'a':
            bla1 =  atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'b':
            myarg = optarg;
            break;
        case 'c':
            bla2 = 1;
            break;
        case 'd':
            bla3 = 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use optarg for case 'b' but in case none is selected to get a default value. Right now requires arg and cannot bypass it and if I replace "b:" with "b" it ignores the argument.

How can I make it work in both situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Some but not all versions of `getopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html) allow you to indicate that an argument is optional by putting *two* colons after the relevant option character.

Wanting an optional argument to an option is a sign that your program is complicated enough that you should consider supporting long option names.  Unfortunately there is no standard function to do this, but GNU libc has two: [`getopt_long`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html) and the even more powerful [`argp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html).  If your software is GPL-compatible, you can get either of them from [gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/MODULES.html) and then you don't depend on glibc.